# How to get currently adding item to SPList from SPItemEventProperties inside event handler?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, event-handling, events, wss-3.0

I'm using ItemAdding Event for one of my SPLists. The question is how I can get the new not yet added item from SPItemEventProperties? I've tried to ListItem.Item but the debuger shows that the property is set to Nothing. Any correction suggest?

Best Regards

T.S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ihe [ItemAdding event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx) fires **before** a recored is actually added so you can't access the fields using .Item.

However you can access everything apart from ID (as its still not been created yet) in the [.AfterProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.afterproperties.aspx) hash table.

Nice code sample

- [How to access fields of List Item in ItemAdding and ItemUpdating event handlers into SharePoint](http://dishashah.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/synchronous-event-hanlders-in-sharepoint-with-itemadding-and-itemupdating/)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it depends on whether your event receiver is running on a List or a Document Library.

Check out this site for handy tables of when `BeforeProperties`, `AfterProperties`, and `properties.ListItem` are populated.

Edit: Link is dead
http://www.synergyonline.com/blog/blog-moss/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=fcb287b5%2D7a1a%2D4206%2Da04f%2D2a97805e4a25&ID=25. I rescued the content using Wayback Machine https://web.archive.org/web/20100623125934/http://www.synergyonline.com/blog/blog-moss/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=fcb287b5-7a1a-4206-a04f-2a97805e4a25&ID=25.

### Original content below by Randy Williams:

As many of you know, event receivers are a great way to hook into various SharePoint events.  These can apply to Feature events such as FeatureActivated, List events such as FieldAdded, and many others.  The most common set of receivers used, however, are part of SPItemEventReceiver which let you wire your code up to a number of events that can occur to items on a list or library.

When working with events, you’ll quickly find that before (synchronous) and after (asynchronous) events exist, and the method suffix such as “ing” (e.g. ItemAdding) and “ed” (e.g. ItemAdded) will tell you whether it gets invoked before or after the actual change is made.  Basic stuff.

And, as you get deeper, you’ll even find that you can extract the before and after state of the change.  For example, you can hook into the ItemUpdating event for a document library and prevent a user from changing a certain column.  The code might look like this:

```
public override void  ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
     if (properties.BeforeProperties["column"] != properties.AfterProperties["column"])
    {
        properties.Cancel = true;
        properties.ErrorMessage = "This column cannot be changed";
    }
}
```

For a document library, this works just fine.  However, you should know that the BeforeProperties hash table is not populated for items on a list.  As is worded in the SDK: “For documents, Before and After properties are guaranteed for post events, such as ItemUpdated, but Before properties are not available for post events on list items”

When they say “not available for post events on list items”, do they mean after events (like ItemUpdated, ItemDeleted, etc)?  The wording is curious here, so I thought I’d take some time to test each combination of common events such as Add, Update and Delete.  These were done across a custom list and then a document library.  Each test involved adding a new item, editing the item and then deleting the item.  Here are the results for a list:

```
List          BeforeProperties  AfterProperties properties.ListItem
ItemAdding    No value          New value       Null
ItemAdded     No value          New value       New value
ItemUpdating  No value          Changed value   Original value
ItemUpdated   No value          Changed value   Changed value
ItemDeleting  No value          No value        Original value
ItemDeleted   No value          No value        Null
```

No value means that column value in the hash table was not available.
New value means that the correct value for the column was available.
Changed value means that the correct updated value was available.
Original value means that the correct original value was available.

Here is the same test against a document library:

```
Library        BeforeProperties  AfterProperties    properties.ListItem
ItemAdding     No value          No value           Null
ItemAdded      No value          No value           New value
ItemUpdating   Original value    Changed value      Original value
ItemUpdated    Original value    Changed value      Changed value
ItemDeleting   No value          No value           Original value
ItemDeleted    No value          No value           Null
```

Properties.ListItem refers the the current value for the list item at that point in the event.  Null means that the item is not available.  My analysis yields the following results:

Not surprisingly, we get null values for for ItemAdding (before item is added) and ItemDeleted (after item is deleted).  This was proven by Ishai Sagi some time ago.
As correctly documented in the SDK, item events for lists do not expose BeforeProperties.
ItemAdding and ItemAdded correctly report the value in the AfterProperties for an list item, but not a library item.  This is curious.
We have no visibility on the previous states during the ItemDeleted event.  Once it’s deleted, it’s clearly gone.

So, if we go back to our original problem listed above.  How can we prevent a user from changing a certain column for an item in a list event?  From the list table, you can see if we hook into the ItemUpdating event, we can compare the current item’s value (properties.ListItem) to the AfterProperties value.  The code would look like this:

```
if (properties.ListItem["column"] != properties.AfterProperties["column"])
{
    properties.Cancel = true;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "This column cannot be changed";
}
```

I hope this post gives you a better idea of how before and after events work for both lists and libraries.  Your comments and feedback are always welcomed.

Comment: Interesting - I would never have guessed they worked slightly differently! I can't imagine why it would be but yet another SharePoint gotcha waiting to trip us up.

Comment: @SteveB I rescued the content using Wayback Machine, hopefully that helps.