# How to change a field value during the ItemUpdating event

Tags: c#, sharepoint, events

I am trying to set the value of a field on a ListItem in an event receiver but its not working

All i am doing during the event is

```
properties.AfterProperties[<field internal name>] = 1;
```

No errors are thrown but the the field i'm setting does not change.
I have also tried

```
properties.ListItem[<field internal name>] = 1;
properties.ListItem.Update();
```

Have also tried SystemUpdate();

I know i am meant to be setting the afterproperties but think i am missing an obvious step.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ItemUpdating is used for validation. If you want to set the values of fields, do it in the ItemUpdated event instead.

Comment: I changed my code to use ItemUpdated instead and by using the ListItem.SystemUpdate(false) i get the result i wanted which is the value i am changing to be included in the last version.

Comment: I'm curious why you say this Rob? An advantage of using ItemUpdating to set field values is that the values will be visible to the user after they submit their changes in a non-datasheet view. Because ItemUpdated is asynchronous, the user may not see their new values when they see the list after submitting the edit.

Comment: This should not be marked as the answer. This is just false, you can definitely set field values during ItemUpdating. @Kit Menke's response should be the answer.

Comment: Do you have an MSDN link or something that says this?

Answer (score 11):

Keep in mind, that depending on whether your event receiver runs on a list or library you may need to use different properties ([see this link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831031/how-to-get-currently-adding-item-to-splist-from-spitemeventproperties-inside-even/2834498#2834498)).

Assuming you are in the `ItemUpdating` method running on a list, all you should need is:

```
base.ItemUpdating(properties);
properties.AfterProperties["InternalName"] = 1;
```

(no updates required since you are changing the value before it gets saved)

I would verify that your Event Receiver is attached to the list. Are you able to debug your Event Receiver when you modify an item in the list?

Comment: The code is defiantly running as I have enterprise logging running. I have the base call after by code so i will try moving that to the top to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Hmm.. are you able to log the value of AfterProperties["InternalName"] before you change it?

Comment: I have loged the value before an after changing and can see the value change. It just isn't saved. Rob Windsor is right. It appears no matter what you do to the after properties it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Buzzby you can save the values see my answer in itemupdating.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, do not forget to call DisableEventFiring, because guess what happens when you call Update method? ItemUpdated event gets called again and you go into an endless loop...

Comment: You mean EventFiringEnabled = false ?

Comment: Depends on which version of SharePoint you use. But for 2010 yes - EventFiringEnabled : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.disableeventfiring.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can add the value in the Item Adding event using the
 AfterProperties.ListItem[]=;

Comment: The listitem object does not exist in AfterProperties

Comment: yes, so you have to use the AfterProperties.ListItem[]=; in item adding event

Answer (score 0):

You can update values of a field in ItemUpdating also, this works for me.

> properties.AfterProperties["FieldName"] = "computedvalue";
>   base.EventFiringEnabled = false; 
>   properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate(false);
>   base.EventFiringEnabled = true;

Answer (score 0):

It is nice to update Title in ItemAdding and ItemUpdating events since extra Updates are avoided (without DisableEventFiring), and the "Edit Properties view" will already have the Title filled in

Some code example to update title based on filename. Works for Document Library and Picture Library. For working with Title in Lists, ["Title"] needs to be used.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdding(properties);
    string currTitle = properties.AfterProperties["vti_title"] as string;
    string url = properties.AfterUrl;
    var name = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //NOTE! Name is only copied to Title if title is not set. Will not handle name changes!
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currTitle))
    {
        properties.AfterProperties["vti_title"] = name;
    }
}
```